# How to factor 5671?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, mental-arithmetic

The other day I wanted to factor 5671 in my head. (It turns out to be $53\cdot107$, but I did not know this at the time.)  I quickly ruled out the easy divisors, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, and 13. At this point I saw no obvious way to proceed short of a very tedious trial division.

But I did notice that 5671 has a residue of 1 modulo 2, 3, 5, and 7. Is there any way to use this coincidence to reduce or simplify the problem of finding a factorization of 5671, perhaps by ruling out certain types of divisors?

Comment: The "Fermat" method works nicely, $5671=80^2-27^2$.

Comment: All that information gives you is that 5670 is a multiple of 210. Not very useful for factorising 5671, I would say.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, how would you go about finding 80 and 27 in your head if you didn't already know the factorisation?

Comment: [Fermat factorization method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method)

Comment: $5671 = 5300 + 371 = 53(100 + 7) = 53*107$

Comment: Sure, but how do you know that until you do trial division by 53?

Comment: @user69810 Well, you might just as well assert that sincce $5671=1+2+3+\dots 106$ you get this factorization. Doesn't seem helpful, however.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, I know. I did do that in my head though. The only tricks I know are how to eliminate the obvious candidates like 2, 3, 5, 9 and 11. Other than that I use brute force.

Comment: In any event, I think @TonyK's answer gives you all you need - the value of knowing a number module $210$ is minimal for knowing how to factor a number relatively prime to $210$.

Comment: I would like to point out that when a number is small such as 5671 it may well be easier just to try dividing by primes less than the square root of the number, because there are not very many such primes and they are small. That is the reason for the solution I gave. Of course, if the number is large then such an approach is not very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to elaborate on the suggestion of using the information about $n = 5671 \equiv 1 \mod {2,3,5,7}$ to find a factoration of $5671$:

Suppose $n = p \cdot q$ for some factors $p$ and $q$, and $n \equiv 1 \mod{2,3,5,7}$. What does this tell us? Well, it gives us four equations in $p$ and $q$:
\begin{align}
p \cdot q &\equiv 1 \mod 2 \\
p \cdot q &\equiv 1 \mod 3 \\
p \cdot q &\equiv 1 \mod 5 \\
p \cdot q &\equiv 1 \mod 7
\end{align}
But since $2,3,5,7$ are primes, any element (but $0$) has an inverse, and so this tells us that:
\begin{align}
q &\equiv p^{-1} \mod 2 \qquad \qquad p,q \not\equiv 0 \mod 2 \\
q &\equiv p^{-1} \mod 3 \qquad \qquad p,q \not\equiv 0 \mod 3 \\
q &\equiv p^{-1} \mod 5 \qquad \qquad p,q \not\equiv 0 \mod 5 \\
q &\equiv p^{-1} \mod 7 \qquad \qquad p,q \not\equiv 0 \mod 7 
\end{align}
In fact, any choice of $p \mod {2,3,5,7}$ is possible, as long as none of those numbers are $0$, and it leads to a unique set of values for $q \mod{2,3,5,7}$. But we already knew that $p, q \not\equiv 0 \mod {2,3,5,7}$, as otherwise one of those numbers $2,3,5,7$ would be a divisor of $n$.

So, a long story short (TL;DR): Knowing that $5671 \equiv 1 \mod {2,3,5,7}$ does not really help you find any of its divisors. It only tells you that $2,3,5,7$ are not divisors of $n$.

(Once you find $p = 53 \equiv (1,2,3,4) \mod {(2,3,5,7)}$, this does tell you that $q \equiv {(1,2,2,2)} \mod {(2,3,5,7)}$. But I suppose that once you know $p$, finding $q$ should not be too hard anyway...)

Answer (score 4):

As two comments have already pointed towards the Fermat factorization method, let's spell out how one might employ it here in a way suitable for mental operation.

We observe that $49<56<81$, so $\sqrt{5671}\approx 70$ (*very* roughly).
More precisely, we have $5671 = 70^2-0^2+771$ and start with the triple $(a,b,c)=(70,0,771)$.
Now repeatedly do the following with the current triple $(a,b,c)$:

- If $c>0$, subtract $a$ from $c$, increase $a$ by one, subtract the new $a$ from $c$ (using two substractions, we avoid computation of $2a+1$).
- If $c<0$, add $b$ to $c$, increase $b$ by one, add the new $b$ to $c$
- If $c=0$, terminate; we have found factors $a+b$ and $a-b$.

In our case the sequence of computation runs like this:
$$(70,0,771)\\(71,0,630)\\(72,0,487)\\(73,0,342)\\(74,0,195)\\(75,0,46)\\(76,0,-106)$$
Note that the steps until now were only necessary because we started with an awfully rough estimate for $\sqrt N$.
Next we use a littel shortcut as we step immediately to $b=\sqrt{|c|}$ and replace $c$ with $c+b^2$
$$(76,10,-6)\\(77,11,15)\\(78,11,-140)\\(78,12,-117)\\(78,13,-92)\\(78,14,-65)\\(78,15,-36)\\(78,16,-5)\\(78,17,27)\\(79,17,-130)\\\vdots\\(80,27,0)$$ 
Admittedly, it does take a while until one reaches a factorization (I left out eleven more steps here), but at least the single steps are very trivial (only addition and subtractions). One can devise some speed-ups for cases when $|c|\gg a,b$, but I'll leave that as an exercise. Depending on your memorizing capabilities, all this may not be suitable for actually doing a *mental* factorization, but it is sure good enough for doing it on a paper napkin. Of course, fastest results are obtained when $b$ is small, i.e. the factors are close to $\sqrt N$.

Comment: To me this seems longer than the "tedious trial division." Also, if you try it with 5779 you will go thousands of steps to find out it's prime.

Answer (score 3):

The comments below the question suggest the Fermat method, but neglects to state how you would go about doing the Fermat method mentally. Here's how I'd approach it mentally.

First, you need to be familiar with all possible 2-digit endings of squares:
$${00, 01, 04, 09, 16, 21, 24, 25, 29, 36, 41, 44, 49, 56, 61, 64, 69, 76, 81, 84, 89, 96}$$

Note that there are several patterns that make this easier:

1) If the units digit of a perfect square is 1, 4, or 9, then the tens digit must be even (01, 21, 41, 61, 81 and 04, 24, 44, 64, 84 and 09, 29, 49, 69, 89).

2) If the units digit of a perfect square is 6, then the tens digit must be odd (16, 36, 56, 76, 96).

3) If the units digit of a perfect square is 0, then the tens digit is also a 0.

4) If the units digit of a perfect square is 5, then the tens digit is a 2.

You should also be able to [square two digit numbers in your head](http://gmmentalgym.blogspot.com/2011/01/squaring-2-digit-numbers-mentally.html#sqbasics) and understand that the [squares of the numbers 1-25 contain every possible 2-digit endings of squares](http://urticator.net/essay/5/590.html).

Using the Fermat approach, we're going to factor the given number *m* in the follow manner:
$$m=A^{2}-B^{2}$$

We start by finding out which 1 of the following 3 questions apply, so that we can work out what values of *A*^2 are worth checking:

1) Are the last 2 digits of *m* also possible as the 2-digit ending of a square? If so, the last two digits of *A*^2 are either 25 or the same as the last 2 digits of *m*.

2) Are the last 2 digits of *m* a hundreds complement (100-last two digits) to the last two digits of a square? If so, the last two digits of *A*^2 are either 00 or equal to the last 2 digits of *m*+25 (mod 100, if needed).

3) If neither of the first two questions apply, then *m* must have a units digit of 3 or 7. Now we can determine the units digit of *A*^2 using these questions:

a) Is the 2-digit ending of *m* equal to 03, 23, 43, 63, or 83? If so, *A*^2 ends in 4.

b) Is the 2-digit ending of *m* equal to 07, 27, 47, 67, or 87? If so, *A*^2 ends in 6.

c) Is the 2-digit ending of *m* equal to 13, 33, 53, 73, or 93? If so, *A*^2 ends in 9.

d) Is the 2-digit ending of *m* equal to 17, 37, 57, 77, or 97? If so, *A*^2 ends in 1.

Shortcut for 3a-3d: If the units digit of *m* is a 3, then the units digit of *A*^2 is a square number (4 or 9). If the units digit of *m* is a 7, then the units digit of *A*^2 is NOT a square number (1 or 6). In both cases, to decide between your two choices here, choose the odd one when then tens digit is odd, and the even one when the tens digit is even.

Let's apply this to the 5671 problem.

Are the last 2 digits, 71, the ending of a perfect square? No, so forget this question.

Can you take the last 2 digits, 71, and add a square ending to get 100? Yes, you can add 29 to make 100. Now we know that *A*^2, if it exists (we still haven't determined whether 5671 is prime), ends in either 00 or 96 (71 + 25).

What numbers will yield a square ending in 00? Anything ending in a multiple of 10. What numbers will yield a square ending in 96? Any number which is 14 away from a multiple of 50 (14, 36, 64, 86, 114, 136, etc.).

Where do we start? Well, 5671 is above 75^2 (5625), so 76 should be our minimum starting point. In other words, we'll check numbers 76 or greater that either end in 0, or are 14 away from a multiple of 50. In other words, we're limiting our possibilities for *A* to 80, 86, 90, 100, 110, 114, and so on.

OK, let's start with 80^2 (6400). Is 6400-5671 a square number? As it happens, the answer, 729, is 27^2! We got lucky on the first try, discovering:
$$5671=80^{2}-27^{2}$$

What does this tell us? Remember:
$$A^{2}-B^{2}=(A+B)(A-B)$$

So, the factors of 5671 are:
$$(80+27)(80-27)\\107\times53$$

Answer (score 1):

In this case it might be just as easy to try all primes less than the square root of 5671. With a pocket calculator this should be very rapid.

Comment: You should know, that probably, you were downvoted because this is not the type of solution for questions in number theory, not because your suggestion is incorrect.

Comment: I downvoted this because it did not at all address the question: Do the modular residues give any help in calculating the factorization, and how can I factor this number in my head. The question also implied that I did not want to perform "a tedious trial division", but that is exactly what this post suggests.

So *for this question*, it was an incorrect answer.